# Finding a closed form of recursive formula $T(n)=4T(n-1) - 4T(n-2)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

> Find the closed form for the following:
>   $$T(n) = \begin{cases} 1\quad &\text{ if } n = 0 \\
>  4\quad &\text{ if }  n = 1 \\ 4T(n-1) - 4T(n-2) & \text{  if } n > 1 \end{cases}$$

Usually I would create a general formula based on $k$ repetitions, then solve for $k$ based on a value of $n$ and substitute. From there it is usually easy to get a formula for the equation in terms of $n$. But I don't see how this would work here.

Comment: Do you use characteristic polnomials (in this case $x^2-4x+4$) in approaching the solutions of such recurrences? There are several approaches, and it would be useful to know which one(s) you have used before.

Comment: Usually I would create a general formula based on k repititions, then solve for k based on a value of n and subsitute. From there it usually easy to get a formula for the equation in terms of n

Comment: The general solution will be $A\cdot 2^n+B\cdot n2^n$, and now one needs to find $A$ and $B$ so that the initial conditions are satisfied.

Comment: @guest2722 When you say "usually", which types of recurrence relations have you used this method on before, and what's different about this one that makes your technique not work?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$T_n=4T_{n-1}+4T_{n-2}$$

Doing substitution $T_n=\alpha^n$ we get

$$\alpha^2-4\alpha+4=0 \implies (\alpha-2)^2=0$$

Thus, the general form of $T_n$ is given by

$$T_n=A\cdot 2^n+B\cdot n2^n$$

We know that $T_0=1$ and $T_1=4$ so finally

$$T_n=2^n+n2^n$$